# how to align controls in android linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am using android studio to design a dashboard. Now I am facing the issue that I have a linear layout where I want 2 buttons in each row, with one button on the left and other at right of the screen. My xml is like this:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/ActivityBody"
            android:orientation="vertical"


            >

   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMaterialIssue"
                    style="@style/DashboardButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/materialissue"
                    android:text="Material Issue"
                    android:onClick="onGol"

                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnWorkCompletion"
                    style="@style/DashboardButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/workcompletion"
                    android:text="Work Completion"
                    android:onClick="onGol"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

My style file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme"></style>

       <style name="Theme.D1t" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.D1" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.tranlucent" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Home">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0</item>
        <item name="android:background">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="HomeText">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize"> 18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/foreground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBar">
        <item name="android:id">@id/title_container</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarOperation">
        <item name="android:layout_width">45dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarLogo">
        <item name="android:id">@id/title_logo</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarText">
        <item name="android:id">@id/title_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/title_text</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextBody">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textBody</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActivityBody">
         <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
         <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>

    </style>
    <style name="DashboardButton">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">9dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources
```

Comment: You better use a RelativeLayout. And get rid of the root layout, which is simply **useless**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `android:layout_weight`
to use layout_weight you want to set `layout_width` as `"0dp"`

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"


<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMaterialIssue"
                    style="@style/DashboardButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/materialissue"
                    android:text="Material Issue"
                    android:onClick="onGol"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnWorkCompletion"
                    style="@style/DashboardButton"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/workcompletion"
                    android:text="Work Completion"
                    android:onClick="onGol"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Width should be 0dp and btnWorkCompletion has two layout_width. Can you edit that please? For the next person who is gonna see this answer.

Comment: @gonchu-golu you are welcome.if this answer help to you please accept this as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to use the relative layout and align them to left and right

below is the code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMaterialIssue"
        style="@style/DashboardButton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/materialissue"
        android:text="Material Issue"
        android:onClick="onGol"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnWorkCompletion"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        style="@style/DashboardButton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/workcompletion"
        android:text="Work Completion"
        android:onClick="onGol"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Option:
   Use margins to the left of right button and to the right of the left button.

   ```
             <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="60dip"
               android:layout_gravity="left"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
               >

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/btnMaterialIssue"
                   style="@style/DashboardButton"
                   android:drawableTop="@drawable/materialissue"
                   android:text="Material Issue"
                   android:onClick="onGol"

                   layout_marginRight="20dp"

                   android:layout_gravity="left"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/btnWorkCompletion"
                   style="@style/DashboardButton"
                   android:drawableTop="@drawable/workcompletion"
                   android:text="Work Completion"
                   android:onClick="onGol"

                   layout_marginLeft="20dp"

                   android:layout_gravity="right"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Option:
   place something (another view (Linearlayout)) in the middle, between the buttons.
3. Option:
   Try to play with layout_weight

   ```
   <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="New Button"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
   <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">
   </LinearLayout>
   <Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="New Button"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: but I want to make it compatible with all screen sizes so I don't want to use constant value in margins. I want to use margin according to screen sizes , just like % in web applications.

Comment: ok then place an linearlayout in the middle of the buttons, than give them layout_weight...

Answer (score -1):

Add all `linearlayout` in `relativelayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

And in linearlayout or button add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddExpense"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stitch_button"
        android:text="@string/add" />
```